# Firefox extension with toolbar

Tags: firefox

I am trying to create a firefox extension (my first extension so I am beginner). 
I wanted to do this example :

[image]

But this is my result :

[image]

I can not understand why my images are not loading, why the frame on the right of the buttons is empty and if it was possible to increase the height of the toolbar.

There is my code :

index.js :

```
var { ActionButton } = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var { Toolbar } = require("sdk/ui/toolbar");
var { Frame } = require("sdk/ui/frame");

var previous = ActionButton({
  id: "previous",
  label: "previous",
  icon: {
      "16": "./icons/previous.png"
    },
    onClick: function(state) {
        console.log("button '" + state.label + "' was clicked");
    }
});

var next = ActionButton({
  id: "next",
  label: "next",
  icon: {
      "16": "./icons/next.png"
    },
    onClick: function(state) {
        console.log("button '" + state.label + "' was clicked");
    }
});

var play = ActionButton({
  id: "play",
  label: "play",
  icon: {
      "16": "./icons/play.png"
    },
    onClick: function(state) {
        console.log("button '" + state.label + "' was clicked");
    }
});

var frame = new Frame({
  url: "./frame-player.html"
});

var toolbar = Toolbar({
  title: "Player",
  items: [previous, play, next, frame]
});
```

frame-player.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    TEST
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting all the files (images, scripts, ...) in the "data" folder of my extension.